# Zend set longer track shortcuts

Tags: debugging, zend-framework

I'm getting some Zend error like:

```
#0 C:\workplace\electro\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(115): Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli->_prepare('SELECT `cm`.`su...')
```

Part of it:

```
'SELECT `cm`.`su...'
```

is only shortcut of parameter. How to see it all or longer part of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this:

```
$request - here your request (Zend\Db\Sql)
$this->_dbTable - database table object (Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway)

Debug::dump($this->_dbTable->selectWith($request));
```

If you need more [info](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html)